# Get Deltas from complex SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, load

I have a complex SQL query that do joins over more than 15 tables, and bring 30 columns. 
Knowing that I have an update date columns on the source tables.

How can I get the deltas of all updated/Inserted information from that query ?

Adding 15 conditions `(DateDiff(d,T1.Update_Date,getdate()) <= @delta OR DateDiff(d,T2.Update_Date,getdate()) <= @delta OR .....)` in the where clause is neither performant nor convenient

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your syntax is a hybrid of MySQL and SQL Server, so I have no idea what database ou re really using.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you do now want to use functions on columns in the `where` clause.  This makes it harder for the optimizer to function.

Instead of:

```
DateDiff(T1.Update_Date, getdate()) <= @delta
```

You want something like:

```
t1.Update_date <= dateadd(day, - @delta, getdate())
```

(This is SQL Server syntax; the idea is the same but the syntax different in other databses).

If you want to check a column in each table, then you need to list out the columns.  Because you are connecting the conditions by `OR`, this probably won't have much impact on performance.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff I tried that, it's the OR condition that makes the query slow. with just one condition on the where clause it works fine.
What if I separate to 15 query with UNION ALL between ?

Comment: @OussamaK . . . `union all` is often much faster than `or` if the subqueries can then better make use of indexes.